# Deleting All Documents in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

There are quite a few tips on the WWW how to delete all documents in a RavenDB database. Some are more complicated than others, i.e. http://vpetroff.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/deleting-all-documents-in-ravendb.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest edition of RavenDB you can simply use the built in Auto/AllDocs index.

```
    private static void DeleteFiles(IDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        var staleIndexesWaitAction = new Action(
            delegate
            {
                while (documentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetStatistics().StaleIndexes.Length != 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            });
        staleIndexesWaitAction.Invoke();
        documentStore.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex("Auto/AllDocs", new IndexQuery());
        staleIndexesWaitAction.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: "Auto/AllDocs" doesn't seem to be working.  @Seth's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using version 3, and `"Auto/AllDocs"` doesn't seem to work. However, you can retrieve the index names and delete that way, for example:

```
        var indexDefinitions = _documentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetIndexes(0, 100);
        foreach (var indexDefinition in indexDefinitions)
        {
            _documentStore.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex(indexDefinition.Name, new IndexQuery());
        }
```